# Unable to print d3 collapsible tree using wkhtml

Tags: javascript, html, django, d3.js

I have webpage in django which has six Highcharts, one d3 collapsible tree and some text. I am trying to print the webpage using wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf. I got it working using following command:

```
wkhtmltopdf --post search_data data-here --custom-header "CONTENT-TYPE" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --javascript-delay 5000 http://localhost:81/url imagename.png
```

But problem is with the d3 charts. It doesn't get printed in the pdf. Even a single dot of it not get printed. Even I have added delay 5000 to the command.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Try this tool instead:http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html